# Calling Service Now Webservice with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, servicenow

I am trying to call Service Now's webservice from .Net and I can make it work fine for inserting a record, but I can not get any `GET`s to work. Here is my working `INSERT` code:

```
public void insertTable(string tableName, string schema, string columnInfo, string shortDesrcipt, string longDescript)
{
    using (ServiceNow_u_database_table tableReference = new ServiceNow_u_database_table())
    {
        insertResponse response = new insertResponse();

        System.Net.ICredentials cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.UserName, Properties.Settings.Default.Password);
        tableReference.Credentials = cred;

        insert tableInsert = this.getTableData(tableName, schema, columnInfo, shortDesrcipt, longDescript);
        try
        {
            response = tableReference.insert(tableInsert);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine. Here is the code that does not work for `GET`:

```
using (ServiceNow_u_database_table tableReference = new ServiceNow_u_database_table())
{
    ServiceNowExport.com.servicenow.libertydev.u_database_table.getRecords recordGet = new getRecords();
    System.Net.ICredentials cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.UserName, Properties.Settings.Default.Password);
    tableReference.Credentials = cred;

    recordGet.name = this._tablePrefix + tableName;
    getRecordsResponseGetRecordsResult[] response = tableReference.getRecords(recordGet);
    if (response != null && response.Count() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run that code, `response` is always `null`. I am following the instructions on [this](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Microsoft_.NET_Web_Services_Client_Examples) page.

I know that it is connecting because if I kill the credentials line I get an unauthorized error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: The snippet you've given for the `Get` seems to be incomplete. What is given here is returning `true` and not `response`. Could that be the reason?

Comment: No , response is checked in the if before you get to the true. That response should have the table it found in it (I know table is there as I created it for this test). The return true is returning that it found the table, but that is not being used right now since I have not gotten past getting the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested I've written a set of soap classes to get and put some information into servicenow. It's pretty limited at the moment to just what I need to be able to do at work, but should work for anyone.

https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/mod-ServiceNOW

Feel free to check it out

Comment: Thanks - but as this question is three years old now, I had forgotten about it. I actually ending up building my own SOAP interface and class from scratch and completely ignored their WSDL. It was the only way to get it to work.  I had full CRUD working, but I no longer work at that company and left the code behind. As far as I know they are still using that code today.

Comment: @VydorScope can you please sir share with us your code?? have you a Github profil ?? i wanna learn from your experience sir , thank you so much

Comment: @Akira Sorry, I left that company many years ago and no longer have access to that code, nor do I work in .NET anymore. I doubt the solution I came up with 8 years ago now is even valid at this point. You would be much better off finding someone far more current in .NET to get help from. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

From the ServiceNow wiki on C# Web Services: [here](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Web_Services_C_Sharp_.NET_End_to_End_Tutorial#Troubleshooting)

> If you are receiving a "null" response from your web service in your
>   client code, then you may have missed the step in this tutorial for
>   setting the elementFormDefault setting to "False" ... Please remember
>   to recompile your code against the WSDL after you have changed this
>   setting and saved it.

The property can be found within the ServiceNow instance at: System
Properties > Web Services. Set it to false, and you should no longer
receive null from the getRecords response.

Here's a screenshot of the property:
[image: Screenshot of the image]

Comment: this should be accepted as Answer! Was very helpful

Comment: +1 Fantastic, I wished I had seen this 3 hours ago :/

Comment: I had already tried this answer before posting the question and it did not work for me. 

I actually ending up building my own SOAP interface and class from scratch and completely ignored their WSDL. It was the only way to get it to work.  I had full CRUD working, but I no longer work at that company and left the code behind. As far as I know they are still using that code today.